# How to deploy zeppelin application to the server?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a zeppelin application running on my local host.I want to deploy it to server. As I am a beginner I don't know the procedure to deploy. If any one have deployed zeppelin to server can you please describe the procedure for it ?

I have checked online source and official tutorial but I am not able to get the steps for its deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by application? Are you just talking about a notebook you created? If so you can simply export the notebook (from the menu in the notebook itself) and import it into the server instance (using import notebook from the splash screen) if it is a vanilla instance.

You will have to make sure the correct interpreter is available and set.

Unless there is something special about the local instance you have deployed, it would be easiest to just deploy it separately to the server using something like Docker.

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/docker.html

Perhaps you can clarify what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I am trying to deploy an notebook instance to any of the server.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, you have created a notebook on your local instance of Zeppelin and you want to copy that notebook to another machine? You would export the notebook. It will prompt you to save as a json file. Then import it from the standard splash page as seen [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html)